# Is there any app like Apple's "Make a call with Wi-Fi Calling" and Can I make an app in android such like apple's?

Tags: android, ios, call, receiver

im a beginner android developer

I am struggling to create a new app as a novice Android developer.

While studying to make, I found an app on the iPhone that has most of the features of the app I want to create.

Apple's "Make a call with Wi-Fi Calling"
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203032

So I would like to make an app that can receive calls from other devices (mainly mobile phones that do not have USIM chips) on Android.

And if you have additional examples for developing related apps or android classes, tutorial, etc you need to use, please let me know.
I do not have a lot of knowledge about this field. If possible, please give detailed explanation.

thank you for your time

have a nice day

Comment: That isn't an app; that is a feature of iOS that works with the mobile carrier to use WiFi instead of 3G/4G for calling.  I think you are asking about writing a VoIP app, which is different.

Comment: paulw11 // thx, but im still looking for a way